# Is electrical induction achieved more efficiently by coiling a wire than using a cylinder?

Tags: inductor, coil, induction

I'm currently learning the concept of electrical induction and came up to a realization that if we use a cylinder or a huge strand of wire/conductor instead of coiling tiny wires, we should be able to achieve the same (or probably greater) electrical induction.

What should be the obvious and scientific difference and implication for this?

Sorry, newbie question here.

Comment: Perhaps you could describe what you have in mind and explain what you mean by "efficiently". If you don't care about resistance, then the least material for the most inductance is achieved by making the wire as thin as possible and maximizing the turns. Inductance is proportional to number of turns squared.

Comment: Explain how you came to this realization, so we can set you straight.

Comment: I think he's imagining a solid, hollow cylinder of copper rather than a bunch of individual strands...?

Comment: Are you saying one humongous turn of 'fat wire' instead of lots & lots of turns of tiny wires?

Comment: See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faraday's law of induction says simply: -

Induced voltage = \$N\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}\$ where N is the number of turns.

So, if you have many turns you get more voltage. This is usually the main motivator for winding many turns but, one turn is fine and can be just as good (and sometimes better) if the frequency is high enough because notice that \$\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}\$ tells you that induced voltage is also proportional to frequency.

However, one further important fact is that a solid sheet conductor in a varying magnetic field will be very inefficient due to eddy currents induced in the sheet. This is why transformers use insulated laminations or ferrite (low conductive materials) in their construction.

These eddy currents sap the field and reduce induction.

Answer (score 1):

Well, induction creates a non-conservative field which means that the electric potential increases along circles.  To make use of that increase in the form of a resulting voltage, we use isolated wires around the magnetic flow change.  You basically propose removing the isolation.  But then you will shortcircuit the induced voltage, leaving no voltage to pick up.

There are actually asynchronous motors with a short-circuit cage of suitable material as rotor, a so-called [squirrel cage rotor.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squirrel-cage_rotor)

This works by the short-circuited voltage creating a circulating current inducing a magnetic field that generates torque against the stators magnetic field.

However, in most applications for induction, you don't want to reinvest the induced voltage immediately into a countermagnetic field, so shortcircuiting it does not actually help the application.